# Loading text boxes with DB values from Combobox Selection

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to populate values in text boxes from existing db based on selection made by user in GUI via combobox.

```
def lookupClassification(event):
    # clear the text boxes
    rate.delete(0, END)
    burden_factor.delete(0, END)
    total_cost.delete(0, END)

    # Create a database or connect to one
    conn = sqlite3.connect('labor_rates.db')
    # Create a cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    classification_selected = classification.get()
    #query the database
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM laborrates WHERE classification = ?', [classification_selected])
    records = c.fetchall()
    #loop through results
    for record in records:
        rate.insert(0, record[1])
        burden_factor.insert(0, record[2])
        total_cost.insert(0, record[3])
        
#combobox options
def class_combo():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('labor_rates.db')
    c = conn.execute('SELECT classification FROM laborrates')
    result = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        result.append(row[0])
    return result

# create text boxes
classification = ttk.Combobox(lr_editor, width = 30, values = class_combo())
classification.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10,0))
classification.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lookupClassification)
```

Once the selection is made no values are populated within the respected text boxes.  I've tried all I can think of and would appreciate any insite.

Comment: You did not tell what went wrong. Either way, your code is prone to SQL injection

Comment: I’ve updated the post.  Text boxes do not have value populate once combobox value is selected

Comment: You should be able to figure out what `records` is first, so `print(records)` before the loop and make sure it is the values you expect

Comment: `<<ComboSelected>>` should be `<<ComboboxSelected>>` instead.  Also `lookupClassification()` should accept an argument, the `Event` object.

Comment: Updated and now getting the following error 
 _sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Foreman_  Also it should be noted that classification is text, rate is integer, burden_factor is real, and total_cost is real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column `classification` is a string and for example `classification_selected = "Foreman"`, then the final SQL of

```py
'SELECT * FROM laborrates WHERE classification = ' + classification_selected
```

will be

```sql
SELECT * FROM laborrates WHERE classification = Foreman
```

It will cause the exception mentioned in the comment.

It is better to use *placeholder* in the SQL in order to avoid SQL injection:

```py
c.execute('SELECT * FROM laborrates WHERE classification = ?', [classification_selected])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @acw1668.  I've updated the code in the post to reflect the corrections!!!